# Editext validation for button click

Tags: android

I have an edittext and when the button is clicked it allows only Strings.

I do this by using an if statement to show a dialog with this condition: `(str.matches("[0-9]*")`

but when I enter this ttttt12323 and press the button it allows string and int to go through.

I want to put validation for not allowing string and text together specifically only Strings.

Can this be done. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [My blog post on Android Edittext Validation](http://piyushnp.blogspot.com/2010/03/android-edittext-validation-example.html) using regular expression.
It may help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to check if your input consists of characters only, right?

You could try something like `(str.matches("[A-Za-z]*")`